# c++ getting dynamic generic type of pointer?

Tags: c++, generics, templates, dynamic

the title probably is misleading, but i didn't really know how to name it.

let's say I have the following structs

```
template <typename T>
struct SillyBase{
   void doFunnyStuff(vector<T> vec){
        dummyField = T();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            vec.push_back(dummyField++);
    }
    T dummyField;
 };

struct A : public SillyBase<char>{};

struct B : public SillyBase<float>{};
```

now let's further assume i have a pointer

```
ISillyBase* ptr;
```

which is pointing to an object of a DECENDANT class (A or B) of SillyBase - however, i DON'T KNOW which one (i just know it's either A or B);

Is there ANY way for me to call doFunnyStuff() ?

maybe something like:

```
vector<dynamic_generic_type_of(ptr)> vec;
ptr->doFunnyStuff(vec);
```

thanks!

Comment: Voted to close as *no longer relevant* because the question of how to call methods on `ptr` is based on the flawed premise that it's possible to declare `ptr` at all.

Comment: What's the bigger problem at hand?

Comment: what 'type' of vector would you expect to pass in? and what values do you want to collect? would you expect to store both char and floats in the vector? so you would convert them to one type anyway ... probably there is a simple solution to your problem but we don't know what is the problem that you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you can't have `SillyBase*` because `SillyBase` is defined as

```
template <typename T> struct SillyBase {...}
```

So you need to provide type ...

Another problem is that you pass a copy of `vector<T>` into `doFunnyStuff()` which you then populate ... that does not seems right because when the method returns you lose your `vec`, was it supposed to be reference `vector<T>&` ?

Comment: you could have in ISillyBase a virtual doFunnyStuff but the problem is that it needs to know the type of parameter ... so it can't be virtual ... maybe explain what you are trying to achieve and there might be easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: even with `ISillyBase`, there is no such thing as virtual template members so you won't be able to define one that takes `vector<T>` parameter.

---

Well in your example, there is no such non template type as `SillyBase` hence you cannot declare `SillyBase* ptr;`

And in the end I don't really see what you're trying to achieve :/

Answer (score 0):

The `SillyBase *ptr;` shouldn't even compile. Without a template parameter list, `SillyBase` isn't a type, so attempting to use it in a context that requires a type should fail.

Since you can't create the pointer in the first place, there's no real answer to how to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually two absolutely different classes. There is no way to call function by name in classes that have met 100 years ago on their aunt wedding. You have to redesign the solution to include some base class for your template classes
like

```
class SillyBaseBase
{
    public:
        void function doFunnyFunnyStuff(SillyBase<char> *)
        {
            SillyBase<char>::doFunnyStuff();
        }

        void function doFunnyFunnyStuff(SillyBase<float> *)
        {
            SillyBase<float>::doFunnyStuff();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the built in dynamic_cast template function. It dynamically determines the type of a data structure and returns null if it is not an instantiation. The syntax is

```
dynamic_cast<the_template_definition>(the_template_instantiation)
```

The one important catch is that the template classes must derive from a common virtual class. So to do what you want, you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Top /* The parent class */ {
public: 
virtual ~Top() {}; // You need one base virtual function in the base class
};

template <typename T> class SillyBase : public Top {
   void doFunnyStuff(T dummyVar){
        dummyField  = dummyField + dummyVar;
    }
    T dummyField;
 };

class A : public SillyBase<char>{};
class B : public SillyBase<float>{};

int main(){
   A a;
   Top *ptr = (Top*)(&a);
   if(dynamic_cast<A*>(ptr) != NULL)
      printf("ptr is of type A*\n");
   if(dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr) != NULL)
      printf("ptr is of type B*\n");
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the program will be:

```
ptr is of type A*
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with the dynamic_cast keyword. Although you would run into a problem when you declare the vector. It would have to be of type SillyBase. The problem with this is that this requires the use of template arguments, which would be unkown and impossible to get. To remedy this problem in the past, I've just put the vector in the Base class of type base, and then providing a functions to modify it. The inheireted class would provide a variable of the same name of the vector's in the base class. The inheireted class, inheiriting the base class's functions would hopefully fill the correct vector. I don't know if this is a good idea or a bad idea, but it's the way I attempted to overcome this problem within my projects.